# CCFH - Do a retransmitted CCR message set the T bit during CCFH failover?

Tags: diameter-protocol

CCFH - Do a CCR message set the T bit during failover ?

## Scenario

1. I have a client and 2 OCS servers.
2. I didnt get the CCA response (CCA -I ) from first OCS.
3. After my TX timer expiry I am retransmitting CCR I to second OCS.

Question here is - 
Do the retransmitted CCR needs the T bit to be set ?

In RFC I cannot see this specifically mentioned anywhere

Answer (score 0):

You can find the answer in the [RFC 4006 Diameter Credit-Control Application](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4006.txt)

> If the timer Tx expires, the credit-control client MUST continue the
>   service and wait for a possible late answer.  **If the request times
>
>   out, the credit-control client re-transmits the request (marked with
>
>   T-flag) to a backup credit-control server, if possible.**  If the re-
>   transmitted request also times out, or if a temporary error is
>   received in answer, the credit-control client buffers the request if
>   the value of the Direct-Debiting-Failure-Handling AVP is set to
>   TERMINATE_OR_BUFFER.